# network icon problem in lxpanel in lubuntu

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, system-tray, lxpanel

I have recently installed lubuntu-desktop in Ubuntu 12.04.

In the lxpanel I have a network icon which shows my current network connection status. I have a wired connection [ethernet] which connects automatically at startup. In Unity or Gnome I observed that this icon changed to to arrows [one up, one down] when wired connection was established. But in lubuntu it showed "disconnected" time icon.

How can I change this network icon to behave like in Unity or Gnome? I am submitting image decribing the situation.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

### Edit

If I connect to internet via mobile broadband the network icon vanishes!
[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like your icon theme doesn't have an Ethernet icon. Try changing your icon theme, and check if the issue persists.

Comment: I have changed icon theme from **Customize Look and Feel** option in **Preferance** but nothing happens.

Comment: I'll go ahead and open a bounty, see if we can find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Simple fix

(Without downloading anything, use 16px icon)

1. Remove old links

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired.svg
   sudo rm /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired-autoip.svg
   ```
2. Make new links to 16px icon

   ```
   sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/16/nm-device-wired.svg /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired-autoip.svg
   sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/16/nm-device-wired.svg /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired.svg
   ```

[image]

### Nice look fix

(Download same theme icon set)

1. Remove old links

   ```
   sudo rm /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired.svg
   sudo rm /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired-autoip.svg
   ```
2. Download `lubuntu-icon-theme` binary (Ubuntu 14.04, from https://launchpad.net/) & extract it

   ```
   wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/156931592/lubuntu-icon-theme_0.42_all.deb
   dpkg-deb -x lubuntu-icon-theme_0.42_all.deb lubuntu-icon-theme/
   ```
3. Copy only *wired* icon  to *elementary* theme folder

   ```
   sudo cp lubuntu-icon-theme/usr/share/icons/lubuntu/panel/22/nm-device-wired.svg /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired.svg
   sudo ln -s /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired.svg /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired-autoip.svg
   ```

[image]

---

**How did I get this?**

1. Trace file opening of `nm-applet` while I change status. (`...` ie lines I removed)

   ```
   $ pkill nm-applet
   $ strace -e trace=open nm-applet
   ...
   open("/usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-no-connection.svg", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 13
   open("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-svg.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 14
   open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 14
   open("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/librsvg-2.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 14
   open("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcroco-0.6.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 14
   open("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 14
   ** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
   open("/usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-no-connection.svg", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 13
   ** Message: applet now embedded in the notification area
   open("/usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-no-connection.svg", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 13
   open("/usr/share/icons/elementary/animations/22/nm-stage01-connecting01.svg", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 13
   open("/usr/share/icons/elementary/animations/22/nm-stage01-connecting02.svg", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 13
   ...
   open("/usr/share/icons/elementary/animations/22/nm-stage03-connecting10.svg", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 13
   open("/usr/share/icons/elementary/animations/22/nm-stage03-connecting11.svg", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 13
   open("/usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired.svg", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 13
   ...
   ```
2. Notice last one, when I connected wired network. Then I check it if it is a file.

   ```
   $ ls -l /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired.svg
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Sep 25  2011 /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired.svg -> nm-no-connection.svg

   $ ls -l /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/*wired*
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Sep 25  2011 /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired-autoip.svg -> nm-no-connection.svg
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Sep 25  2011 /usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired.svg -> nm-no-connection.svg
   ```

It was a link to `nm-no-connection.svg` same as `/usr/share/icons/elementary/panel/22/nm-device-wired-autoip.svg`. That was the problem.

Comment: This answer has the highest rating. Was it the correct solution to the problem?

Comment: What I can say, I have tested it on fresh Ubuntu 12.04.2 after I have installed `lubuntu-desktop`. It works. But I hope someone else confirm it (Votes are still low,So it doesn't mean always it works).

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if this question was possibly abandoned by the asker. If that's the case, they wouldn't assign a correct answer, so we'd be working off ratings.

Comment: Bounty awarded to this answer. Bounty was close to expiring, this answer was most upvoted and had most detail.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend first trying to change either the icon theme, or the color of the icon set. Personally, I use the aw0ken icon theme set, as I find it to be very aesthetic. You can download it, along with many other icon sets for openbox, at http://box-look.org/ (you can select "icons" from the options on the left side of the main screen.